# Hierarhical Multi-index counts in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a multi-index dataframe in Pandas, e.g:

```
                         A         B         C
X      Y     Z                                
bar   one    a   -0.007381 -0.365315 -0.024817
             b   -1.219794  0.370955 -0.795125
baz   three  a    0.145578  1.428502 -0.408384
             b   -0.249321 -0.292967 -1.849202
      two    a   -0.249321 -0.292967 -1.849202
      four   a    0.211234 -0.967123  1.202234
foo   one    b   -1.046479 -1.250595  0.781722
             a    1.314373  0.333150  0.133331
qux   one    c    0.716789  0.616471 -0.298493
      two    b    0.385795 -0.915417 -1.367644
```

How can I count how many levels are contained within another level? (e.g. level `Y` within `X`)

E.g. in the case above the answer would be:

```
X    Y 
bar  1
baz  3
foo  1
qux  2
```

## Update

When I try `df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).count()[0]` I get:

```
            C  D  E
A    B             
bar  one    1  1  1
     three  1  1  1
flux six    1  1  1
     three  1  1  1
foo  five   1  1  1
     one    1  1  1
     two    2  2  2
```

Comment: Does this do what you want: `df.groupby(level=0).count()[0]`?

Comment: Thanks @EdChum I think it doesn't (I updated the DF to show a case where it would fail).

Comment: Yes it would not work in that case. how about `df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).count()[0]`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do the following (group by level `X` and then calculate the number of unique values of `Y` in each group, which is easier when the index is reset):

```
In [15]: df.reset_index().groupby('X')['Y'].nunique()
Out[15]: 
X
bar    1
baz    3
foo    1
qux    2
Name: Y, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 10):

I think this must work as well:

For level A:

```
df.groupby(level='A').size()
```

For level B:

```
df.groupby(level=['A','B']).size()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always add suffix to your column name and reset index after converting to dataframe.

Let's say I have pandas.series.Series object "s"

```
>> s = train.groupby('column_name').item_id.value_counts()
>> type(s)
pandas.core.series.Series
>> y = x.to_frame()
>> data = y.add_suffix('_Count').reset_index()
>> data.head() #It will be pandas dataframe with column updates with suffix "_Count"
```

I converted multi index series object to single level indexed dataframe.